# SQLite: query to return either distinct value or NULL

Tags: sql, sqlite

In an sqlite3 database, I have a column called date. I need a query that, if all date values are identical, returns the identical value. If they are not, it should return NULL.

How can I best express this in SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(DateColumn) = MAX(DateColumn) 
                THEN MIN(DateColumn) 
                ELSE NULL                       -- not needed, added for clarity
       END AS result
FROM TableX ;
```

Not sure about SQLite but in most DBMS, if there is an index on `(DateColumn)` the MIN/MAX condition will be much more efficient than any query with `COUNT()`.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. Is it better to use `min` and `max` or to write `WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT DateColumn) = 1`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT DateColumn) = 1
            THEN DateColumn
            ELSE NULL
        END AS result    
FROM YourTable;
```